# Spring Dispatcher servlet for static html files and default path

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

Spring 3.1.4
Java 1.7

I have a webapp with a DispatcherServlet configured for all urls. Most of them will have mapping. There are some static files in the application which when I access using `http://host:port/myapp/index.html` correctly displays the contents of the index.html under the web directory. I achieve this by using the following snippet in myapp-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

I *expected* that when the url `http://host:port/myapp` was accessed the default index.html would be rendered because I have the following in my web.xml

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

However this does not appear to be the case, i.e, unless the index.html is specified in the URL the DispatcherServlet is not able to resolve it properly. Can someone tell me how this can be achieved? The server logs tell me the following

```
o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/myapp] - servletPath=null, pathInfo=null, queryString=null, name=default
o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/myapp] -  Named Dispatcher Forward
o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/myapp] -  Disabling the response for futher output
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'myapp': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The servlet takes precedence above the `<welcome-file-list>`, so in this case the `<welcome-file-list>` will have no effect because the `DispatcherServlet` consumes all requests, I'm afraid.

The solution is simple however, just add a mapping for the default path *in Spring* and an controller action sending the view to `index.html`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have properly configured for Spring MVC, then it should be something like this,

```xml
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Now you should have one file myapp-servlet.xml in which you should provide mappings for what to do against the requested URL PATTERN or you can go for annotations based mapping in java files directly.

in this case your welcome-file will not play rule as your first request "AppName/" will pass the mvc mapping "/*" and will go for searching mapping in Spring MVC file.

you can achieve your need by this way mapping,

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mvc/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

now MVC will come into picture only if pattern follows "/mvc/" otherwise it will work in normal flow.